# How do I get a nested form working with formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Whenever I do the following it won't display any of the sub fields on the form:

```
= f.semantic_fields_for :transfers do |g|
```

If I singularize it, they display but then the model has no clue what to do with `:transfer`. I tried to do singular for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to match, but that didn't work either.

Transaction:

```
has_many :transfers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :transfers
```

Transfer:

```
belongs_to :transaction
```

view:

```
= semantic_form_for [@user, @transaction], url: url, style: "width: inherit;" do |f|
  = f.semantic_fields_for :transfers do |g|
    = g.inputs do
      = g.input :amount
      %li
        %label
        = "(#{Transfer::TRANSFER_FEE.format :symbol} transaction fee will be added)"
    = g.inputs do
      %li
        %label
        Click
        %input{ type: "image", value: "submit", style: "vertical-align: middle;",
          src: "https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" }
        or fill in your credit card information below
    = g.inputs do
      = g.input :first_name
      = g.input :last_name
      = g.input :card_type, as: :select, collection: [["Visa", "visa"], ["MasterCard", "master"], ["Discover", "discover"], ["American Express", "american_express"]]
      = g.input :card_number
      = g.input :card_verification
      = g.input :card_expires_month, as: :select, collection: (1..12)
      - year = Time.now.year
      = g.input :card_expires_year, as: :select, collection: (year..(year+25))
  = f.inputs do
    %li
      %label
      %input{ type: "submit", value: "Buy", name: "use_cc" }
```

Comment: Does the inputs block (line 3) needs to be outside of the semantic_fields_for block?

Comment: It doesn't need to be be there, but it doesn't affect it either.

Comment: Sorry, I worded my question oddly. Just to clarify, if you wrap the semantic_fields_for block in an inputs block, it has no effect?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference either. I've even tried using the alternate and it will only display the fields if I set it up with the wrong pluralization.

    `= f.inputs :amount, for: :transfers`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't building a transfer object.

In the controller

```
@transaction = current_user.transactions.build
@transaction.transfers.build
```

I hadn't added the second line.